# Why is efficency of Gaussian Elimination O(n^3)?

Tags: computational-complexity, gaussian-elimination

Why is efficency of Gaussian Elimination $O(n^3)$?
See [Big O Notations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Computational_efficiency) states that it is $O(n^3)$ because it requires:

- $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ divisions
- $\frac{2n^3 + 3n^2 − 5n}{6}$ multiplications
- $\frac{2n^3 + 3n^2 − 5n}{6}$ substractions

i.e. an average of $\frac{2n^3}{3}$ operations.
And the proof is in *Farebrother, R.W. (1988), Linear Least Squares Computations*, which I was not able to find for free on the internet.

So here is my interpretation of the result:

- $n$ equations with $n$ variables so it requires $n$ pivots -> $O(n)$
- for each pivot we substract a multiple of row from each other row - >$O(n^2)$
- Total runtime is $O(n^2 n) =O(n^3)$